# Flutter layout with grid at center

Tags: gridview, layout, dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a Flutter layout with 6x6 square table (grid) at the center of the screen and some elements above/below the grid. What is the best way to do so?

I've implemented centered grid as

```
Center() => AspectRatio(aspectRatio: 1) => GridView();
```

but how to place the rest elements? I thought about using Stack() but decided that this is not the best solution. Or should I do this using Row() widget, and if so, how do I align second child of the row in center?

Thanks for your help!

UPD: [Here's the picture of what I meant to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKCr8.png). I want to place two more containers below and above the grid and want them to fill all available space

Comment: Add a visual example of what you want. As it's hard to understand

Comment: Did you take a look at the Stack class https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Comment: Yes, I did. But my widgets won't overlap each other, so I prefer not to use Stack.

Comment: I know the question has been answered, but feel free to have a look at this awesome guide to flutter layouts https://github.com/bizz84/layout-demo-flutter I found it to be very useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's how I did it using Column widget to align elements below and above the grid and Expanded to make Grid visible in the Column widget:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(children: [
        new Text('app'),
        new Expanded(
            child: new Center(
                child: new Container(
                    height: [EXPECTED_GRID_HEIGHT],
                    child: GridView.count(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                      crossAxisCount: 4,
                      children: [GRID_ELEMENTS],
                    )))),
        new Text('app'),
      ]),
    ));
```

Answer (score 40):

There is a very simple way.

Just set `shrinkWrap: true` which makes the `GridView` to take minimum space and wrap the `GridView` with `Center` widget.

```dart
  body: Center(
    child: GridView.count(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      crossAxisCount: 4,
      children: childrenWidgets,
      childAspectRatio: r,
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Thanks, save my life.

Comment: Thanks, `shrinkWrap: true,` is what I want.

Comment: this should be updated as the correct approach I believe.

Comment: This isn't an ideal solution because of the scroll behaviour. I would like to centre things inside a Grid and not the Grid itself inside another Widget.